# How to test if the influence of changing a parameter is larger than the influence of random noise?

Tags: random-generation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have an algorithm under test that generates a vector of results, influenced by an underlying RNG. I want to test whether, when I change parameter *a*, the results change 'more' then when changing the seed of the RNG.

My current method is:

- generate 10 result vectors using different seeds
- perform KS test between each of them to get their average difference
- generate 1 result vector with a fixed seed, changing parameter *a*
- perform a KS test between this result vector and the 10 ones from before
- compare results between first and second KS test

I feel like there must be a better way out there.